# Como buscar o Uri da Galeria no Android 7 nougat

Tags: android

Estou fazendo uma aplicação onde busco uma imagem na galeria do Android Nougat e enviar para um servidor. Porém não estou conseguindo recuperar o Uri com o endereço da imagem para que seja enviada.

```
if(camera.equals("galeria")){
        startActivityForResult(getPickImageChooserIntentGaleria(), 150);
    }
    else{
        startActivityForResult(getPickImageChooserIntentGaleria(), 200);
    }
```

---

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        if (requestCode == 200) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img_imagem);
            if (getPickImageResultUri(data) != null) {
                picUri = getPickImageResultUri(data);

                try {
                    myBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), picUri);
                    myBitmap = rotateImageIfRequired(myBitmap, picUri);
                    myBitmap = getResizedBitmap(myBitmap, 500);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                myBitmap = bitmap;
                imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == 150) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img_imagem);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            try {
                Uri originalUri = data.getData();
                String pathsegment[] = originalUri.getLastPathSegment().split(":");
                String id = pathsegment[0];
                final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Uri uri = getUri();
                Cursor imageCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, imageColumns, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=" + id, null, null);

                if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    String value = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                    picUri = Uri.parse(value);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    private Uri getUri() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(!state.equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            return MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        return MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }
```

---

Para o requestCode == 150 recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-VINHOS.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

---

E para o requestCode == 200 recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
```

---

Estou utilizando esse projeto como base: http://www.journaldev.com/13270/android-capture-image-camera-gallery#comment-39227

Quando é feita a captura de imagem pela câmera é possível obter o caminho da Uri corretamente, mas quando é pela Galeria o valor na Uri fica assim:

```html
picUri = content://media/external/images/media/5168
picUri.getPath() = /external/images/media/5168
```

Preciso receber o Uri neste formato

```
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-VINHOS.jpg
```

---

Gostaria de uma ajuda para resolver este problema.

Comment: Veja este link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=pt-br

Comment: voce precisa solicitar a permissão em tempo de execução

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma: No código que utilizei como base, acrescentei a permissão: permissions.add(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

ficando desta forma :

```
    permissions.add(CAMERA);
    permissions.add(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    permissionsToRequest = findUnAskedPermissions(permissions);
    //get the permissions we have asked for before but are not granted..
    //we will store this in a global list to access later.

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (permissionsToRequest.size() > 0)
            requestPermissions(permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[permissionsToRequest.size()]), ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A partir do **Android 6.0 (nível de API 23)**, os usuários concedem permissões a aplicativos enquanto eles estão em execução, não quando eles são instalados.

Essa abordagem otimiza o processo de instalação de aplicativos, pois o usuário não precisa conceder permissões ao instalar ou atualizar o aplicativo.

Ela também confere ao usuário mais controle sobre os recursos do aplicativo.

Por exemplo, um usuário poderia optar por permitir que um aplicativo de câmera tenha acesso à câmera, mas não à localização do dispositivo. O usuário pode revogar as permissões a qualquer momento na tela Settings do aplicativo.

Adicione a seguinte linha em seu `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Activity**

```
  import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MessageView extends AppCompatActivity {

        private final int CODE_PERMISSION = 123;
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            checkPermission();
        }

        private void checkPermission() {
            // Verifica necessidade de verificacao de permissao
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Verifica necessidade de explicar necessidade da permissao
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, CODE_PERMISSION);
                } else {
                    // Solicita permissao
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            CODE_PERMISSION);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            // Verifica resultado
            if (requestCode == CODE_PERMISSION) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "É necessário a permissão para continuar!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: O projeto que estou utilizando como base já possui esta permissão, porém inclui também esse código e não obtive a URI da galeria.
 http://www.journaldev.com/13270/android-capture-image-camera-gallery#comment-39227

Answer (score 0):

`data.getData()` te retorna a uri para a intent `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`

Comment: O resultado desta  sugestão foi: data.getData() = content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A5168